# Django form submission redirection issue

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-views

I have created a customer model and a store model. when I add/edit a store via form its getting redirected to the empty list of page rather than list of stores. I will have to refresh the page to see the content. 
Here is my code, can someone help me to identify the mistake and correct please?

Views:

```
class CustomerDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'customerdetail_view'
    queryset = Customer.objects.order_by('id')
    model = Customer
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = 'App_CUS/customer_detail.html'


def save_store_formview(request, form, template_name):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            stores = Store.objects.all()
            data['html_store_list'] = render_to_string('App_CUS/stores/partial_store_list.html', {
                'stores': stores
            })
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    context = {'form': form}
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string(template_name, context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)


def store_createview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StoreForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = StoreForm()
    return save_store_formview(request, form, 'App_CUS/stores/partial_store_create.html')


def store_updateview(request, pk):
    store = get_object_or_404(Store, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StoreForm(request.POST, instance=store)
    else:
        form = StoreForm(instance=store)
    return save_store_formview(request, form, 'App_CUS/stores/partial_store_update.html')  

def store_deleteview(request, pk):
    store = get_object_or_404(Store, pk=pk)
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        store.delete()
        data['form_is_valid'] = True
        stores = Store.objects.all()
        data['html_store_list'] = render_to_string('App_CUS/stores/partial_store_list.html', {
            'stores': stores
        })
    else:
        context = {'store': store}
        data['html_form'] = render_to_string('App_CUS/stores/partial_store_delete.html', context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Forms:

```
class StoreForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Store
    fields = '__all__'
```

html:

```
    {% for store in customerdetail_view.stores.all %}
      <tr class="item">
        <td>{{store.store}}</td>
        <td>{{ store.customer }}</td>
        <td>{{ store.status }}</td>
        <td>{{ store.description }}</td>
        <td style="width: 150px">
          <button type="button"
                  class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm js-update-store" style="border:none;"
                  data-url="{% url 'App_CUS:store_update' store.id %}">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit
          </button>
          <button type="button"
                  class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm js-delete-store" style="border:none;"
                  data-url="{% url 'App_CUS:store_delete' store.id %}">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    {% empty %}
      <tr>
        <td colspan="8" class="text-center bg-warning">No Stores</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Ajax code:

```
$(function () {

  /* Functions */

  var loadForm = function () {
    var btn = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      url: btn.attr("data-url"),
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function () {
        $("#modal-store .modal-content").html("");
        $("#modal-store").modal("show");
      },
      success: function (data) {
        $("#modal-store .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
      }
    });
  };

  var saveForm = function () {
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      url: form.attr("action"),
      data: form.serialize(),
      type: form.attr("method"),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        if (data.form_is_valid) {
          $("#store-table tbody").html(data.html_store_list);
          $("#modal-store").modal("hide");
        }
        else {
          $("#modal-store .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  };


  /* Binding */

  // Create store
  $(".js-create-store").click(loadForm);
  $("#modal-store").on("submit", ".js-store-create-form", saveForm);

  // Update store
  $("#store-table").on("click", ".js-update-store", loadForm);
  $("#modal-store").on("submit", ".js-store-update-form", saveForm);

  // Delete store
  $("#store-table").on("click", ".js-delete-store", loadForm);
  $("#modal-store").on("submit", ".js-store-delete-form", saveForm);

});
```

I assume that the mistake like at "stores = Store.objects.all()" under the function "save_store_formview". Since, this doesnt could not take us to the particular Customer's list of stores? it displays a warning message "No Stores" as specified in html. How could I make it return to the list of a particular customer's list of data (stores) once the form (add/edit store) is submitted rather than hitting "No Stores" condition?

I am learning Django and followed a tutorial from simpleisbetterthancomplex by Vitor. Thanks!

Comment: Nothing here does any sort of redirection at all. I assume that is being done in the Ajax code that calls this; if so, you should post it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, added Ajax code.. this code works when adding customers and it just takes you to the list of customers. but when I use it for addition of store under a customer it fails and display "No Stores" warning though that particular customer has got some stores.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Well as I say it is not at all clear what you are asking. What does that HTML relate to? Which view is displaying it? Nothing you have shown creates a context item named `customerdetail_view` so it's not surprising it is empty,

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this was just an error in posting, but you're missing indentation for the statements below `def save_store_formview(request, form, template_name):`

This would mean there is no body to your function - which would cause a lot of issues.

Comment: corrected the Indentation. well, it was just a mistake while pasting the code here. Issue is that it works for customer list but not for store list of a customer!